# js hide/unhide with css formatting

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, hover, fade

I have the following js script which (on its own it works fine really):

```
<style>
<!--
.hide { display: none; }
.unhide { 
display: block; 
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}
-->
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function unhide(divID) {
var item = document.getElementById(divID);
if (item) {
    item.className=(item.className=='hide')?'unhide':'hide';
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="col2">
<a href="javascript:unhide('content1');">
Title of Content</a>
</div>
<div id="col2">
<div id="content1" class="hide">
Body of content
</div>
</div>
```

Left alone, this produces output, at least.  But I want to format this according to this css code:

```
 a.unhide li {
 background: #fff;
 font: 20px century schoolbook, serif;
 }
 a.unhide li:hover {
 background: #ddd;
 text-decoration:underline;
 padding: 3px 8px;
 display: table-row;
 line-height: 500%;
 transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
 }
 .hide {
 font: 20 px century schoolbook, serif;
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 }
```

So how can I possibly "pair" all this?  I've posted elsewhere and people have been stumped. Please help.  I can induce changes into just about every aspect BUT the "unhide" portion of the js script.  It does not cooperate with me ;( Basically I want a #ddd hover effect over the "unhide" link and all content to be in century schoolbook.  Please help. Thank you.

Comment: please improve your question, means  put html according to your last css then we can help to make js

Comment: hey developerCK I'm not sure what "means put html according to you last css" means.  Can you clarify?  Sorry I'm still very much a newbie programming.

Comment: you are making css for li , am i right(a.unhide li) but given html code does not contain li.

Comment: Just updated my answer. Check also what I wrote about css.

Comment: hey developerCK, thanks for clarifying...yes, in my html I've sort of inserted <ul class> to get the li effect (the css is an external file).  Basically it would be: <div id="col2">
<a href="javascript:A.UNHIDE LI('content1');">  
Title of Content</a>
</div>  but the A.UNHIDE LI just looks wrong to my eye...

Comment: Did you check my demo? without ids

Comment: sorry developerCK...just to be sure, your recommendation is --> so your recommendation is--> <div id="col2">
<a href="javascript:A.UNHIDE LI('content1');">
Title of Content</a>
</div>   then?

Comment: Hi Sergio, yes, I'm on jsfiddle right now

Comment: If the html is as you posted above then my answer should work. If you have a `<li>` element I don't know where it is, you need to update your post with correct html.

Comment: Now you updated your code with errors, you cannot have CSS inside the href like that. Leave the function name as it was: `<a href="javascript:unhide('content1');">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem might be that you have double [**IDs**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html/18453687#18453687). IDs cannot be duplicate, they have to be unique. You can give them a class instead.

Try this instead:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <a href="javascript:unhide('content1');">
    Title of Content
    </a>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="content1 hide">Body of content</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function unhide(divID) {
    var item = document.getElementsByClassName(divID)[0];
    console.log(item);
    console.log(item.className ==  divID + ' hide');
    if (item) {
        item.className = (item.className ==  divID + ' hide') ? divID + ' unhide' : divID + ' hide';
    }
}
```

### **Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ADALv/1/)**

In your CSS you are applying the hover to a `a.unhide li:hover {`. Is that what you want? I see no `li` in your code and the `content1` in your code is a `div` not a `a`.

Comment: yes, a.unhide li:hover {.   so I should have content1 as <a href="content1" class="hide">

Comment: @AlexanderTrahaj, is there a `<li>` inside the `<a>`? I don't see that in your code

Comment: Hey Sergio - jsfiddle is giving me a bit of trouble. I can make changes but I can't "run" those changes...

Comment: @AlexanderTrahaj, do you see the "run" button? otherwise you can update and give me back the link

Comment: I actually did not realize i needed to make an account.  Just did.  there should be an <li> in the <a> .  I left it out. I apologize.  Also, I'm running through the code but clicking "title of content" doesn't hind/unhide the body of content though.

Comment: @AlexanderTrahaj, hide/unhide? You wanted to add classes that had a different `:hover` color, or? Please update the code and show me the link so I understand better what you mean.

Comment: I was hoping to give the background of the text a fade -->

Comment: --> a.unhide li:hover {
 background: #fff;
 padding: 3px 8px;
 display: table-row;
 line-height: 500%;
 font: 20px century schoolbook, serif;
 transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
 }

Comment: Your problem here was with IDs, I gave you a solution with classes because you cannot have double IDs. Was that helpful? Check this when you have the mouseover after clicking http://jsfiddle.net/ADALv/5/

Comment: wow! thank you.  I had completely overlooked my use of IDs!!!! Learning by fire i guess!  Just one thing.  I need the hove "effect" over "unhide"...basically over the link named "Title of Content".

Comment: thank you for this...I'm getting there...would the html be compatible with a onmouseover instead of onclick.  Anyway, I'm in the US, and it's about 3 in the morning here, so I have to get some sleep. I am exhausted!  I will play/work with this code on Sunday.  Thank you again!